# Run AHK script as admin on startup

Tags: admin, autohotkey, startup

I have four AHK scripts which run on startup, as they have shortcuts placed in my startup folder. How can I make them run as admin?

What I've tried:

I've tried changing their properties to be run as admin, but they just don't run (when I do that).

I've tried changing their shortcuts' properties to be run as admin, but they too just don't run (when I do that).

I've looked at [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/ac1epn/groggy_guide_admin_rights_privilege_level/) on the topic, but I don't know how to implement that code in the scripts.

I've tried creating a basic C++ application which runs them with `system("start path\\to\\script")`, but it wouldn't compile.

In case it matters, the scripts in question are [ahk-active-screenshot](https://github.com/altbdoor/ahk-active-screenshot), [CtrlAlt_Switch.ahk](https://github.com/The-SamminAter/Scripts/blob/master/CtrlAlt_Switch.ahk), [Kill.ahk](https://github.com/The-SamminAter/Scripts/blob/master/Kill.ahk), and a modified version of [this search script](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/13404-google-search-on-highlighted-text/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can allow the script to **automate administrative programs without running as admin**, here're the required steps:

1. When installing AHK, check the "Add 'Run with UI Access' to context menus" option.
2. After installation, find `AutoHotkeyU64_UIA.exe` on your disk.
3. Open the `.ahk` script's properties, change the "Open with" option to the `AutoHotkeyU64_UIA.exe` you just found.
4. Create a shortcut to this script.
5. Open `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` in the file explorer.
6. Move that shortcut to this folder.

And you're done.

---

How does it work?

The "Add 'Run with UI Access' to context menus" option provides a workaround for common [UAC-related issues](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#uac) by allowing the script to automate administrative programs without running as admin.

Reference: [Run with UI Access](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Program.htm#Installer_uiAccess).

Answer (score 4):

Find the [UIA version](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Program.htm#Installer_uiAccess) of autohotkey on your machine. For me it is at `C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkeyU64_UIA.exe`.

In your startup folder, create a new shortcut (probably one for each of the scripts you want) as follows (replacing paths as appropriate):

- Target: "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkeyU64_UIA.exe" "D:\path\to\script.ahk"
- Start in: "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey"

This launches your script as an admin using the UIA version of AHK on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to top of your scripts:

```
If (!A_IsAdmin)  ; IF NOT Admin
{
    Run, *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Run script as admin
    ExitApp  ; Exit the current instance running without admin privileges
}
MsgBox, 262144, , Running with admin privileges!  ; Continue your code...
```

1. `A_IsAdmin` is a built in variable that returns 1 if current user has admin rights, otherwise returns 0.
2. It first checks if user is **NOT** admin (`!A_IsAdmin`).
3. If user is not admin, it runs the same script which it gets the full path with the built in variable `"%A_ScriptFullPath%"`. The `*RunAs` parameter runs the script as admin.
4. `ExitApp` exits the current script if it does not have admin rights.
5. The `Run` command runs the script again with admin rights, now the script has admin rights, it skips the `IF` condition and executes code below.