# Run AHK script as admin without hitting "run as administrator"

Tags: admin, autohotkey, uac

Is it possible to have an AHK script instantly run as admin without me having to right-click on it? I would like to have the UAC prompt pop up when I double-click the script.

**(Sorry if I am bad at explaining I am a beginner)**

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68855449/7881859).

Answer (score 1):

You this snippet from the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs) to automatically relaunch any script as admin (if it already wasn't ran as admin).

```
full_command_line := DllCall("GetCommandLine", "str")

if (!(A_IsAdmin or RegExMatch(full_command_line, " /restart(?!\S)")))
{
    try
    {
        if (A_IsCompiled)
            Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%" /restart
        else
            Run *RunAs "%A_AhkPath%" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    }
    ExitApp
}
```

Just make sure this is in the [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) (the top of the script).

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to the AHK script (or to the compiled EXE that you made from it). In the properties for the shortcut, select the SHORTCUT tab, and click on the ADVANCED button. On the popup, put a check in the RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR box, then click OK, APPLY, OK

Answer (score 0):

Add this to top of your scripts:

```
If (!A_IsAdmin)  ; IF NOT Admin
{
    Run, *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Run script as admin
    ExitApp  ; Exit the current instance running without admin privileges
}
MsgBox, 262144, , Running with admin privileges!  ; Continue your code...
```

1. `A_IsAdmin` is a built in variable that returns 1 if current user has admin rights, otherwise returns 0.
2. It first checks if user is **NOT** admin (`!A_IsAdmin`).
3. If user is not admin, it runs the same script which it gets the full path with the built in variable `"%A_ScriptFullPath%"`. The `*RunAs` parameter runs the script as admin.
4. `ExitApp` exits the current script if it does not have admin rights.
5. The `Run` command runs the script again with admin rights, now the script has admin rights, it skips the `IF` condition and executes code below.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**